# What role does よかった play in this exchange?

Tags: words

It's from [twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/itoi_shigesato/status/169661833395961856).

```
hetusa: 福岡県筑後、羽犬塚から行方不明になっていた叔母(73才)が発見された、と知らせがありました。
itoi_shigesato: よかった。
hetusa: ありがとうございました
```

My feeling is that it says something like 'just so'.

Also, it common to respond to よかった with gratitude?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`よかった` means that the speaker was glad that the lost person was found.

I'm not sure that `ありがとうございました` is a direct response to `よかった`, rather it's expressing gratitude for the other person showing concern about the lost person.

Answer (score 5):

よかった is used here to express a feeling of relief ( Thank goodness! ).
Intonation is important for this use: ああ、よかった!

Some situations where you can use the expression:
- you lose the wallet but you find it
- nobody is hurt in a traffic accident
- the goalkeeper of your soccer team stops a penalty kick

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by “Intonation is important for this use: ああ、よかった!”  The intonation is always important to some extent, but I do not know if the intonation is particularly important with the sentence “よかった.”  Also, I do not know which intonation you are referring to by writing “ああ、よかった!”

Comment: Intonation does not change its meaning.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want to know that よかった is the accomplished form of [良]{よ/い}い that you know from simple sentences like *いいです*. This word did not came out of nowhere.